# code working in jsfiddle but not when previewed in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I've been struggling all day to make a nav bar that applies certain styles to the link that is currently in use (so if you're on the 'about' page the 'about' link is styled differently to the rest).

I have finally managed to do this in jsfiddle now but when I apply the same code in my text editor and then preview the file in the browser the relevant effect doesn't work, even though it does in JSfiddle.

I've done a fair bit of research but cant find out why, I don't think I have any invisible characters anywhere and ive set the fiddle to 'no wrap in head' and included a document ready command in the script but still nothing.

If anyone could have a look and lend some advice that would be really appreciated, this is driving me nuts!

Fiddle is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/smokescreen/jkLam/

This is my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('li a').click(function(e){
$('a').removeClass('current');$(this).addClass('current');});
});
</script>
```

Oh and the problem is that although in the fiddle when you click on a link it is highlighted green with white text until you then click on another link when previewed in browser this doesn't happen.

The hover effect still works so the link shows up green with white text when hovered over but even when clicked once the mouse is moved away the link reverts to its original state even though it has been clicked and should now be green with white text?!

Comment: Do you have jQuery referenced in your preview?

Comment: yes, i have referenced a jQuery file in the head of the html file after the css

Comment: Do you get any javascript exceptions when debugging?

Comment: im not sure exactly what you mean? im not getting any coding errors in the hints from my text editor and as I say it is all working perfectly in jsfiddle

Comment: @Smokescreen If you open the developer tools panel for your browser (IE, Chrome, and Firefox all have them built in), you can look in the Console tab and see if the script is producing any errors.  I'm pretty sure that F12 opens the panel in all three browsers.

Comment: ok developer tools say theres an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jQuery.js:1 and Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, not quite sure what this means though?

Comment: @Smokescreen Update your question with the full document from your text editor.  That way we can see where the syntax error lies.

Comment: thanks joe but somehow it now seems to be working, ive shown the answer below, think i needed to reference the div the li items were in and not just li items themselves

Answer (score 2):

Add this inside of your `<head>` element:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update** Try removing the class from the element with the class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li a').on('click', function(e){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Comment: i already had a jQuery library referenced but i tried this instead and unfortunately it still doesnt work

Comment: @Smokescreen Are you able to get anything to fire on `ready()`?  Like an alert or `console.log()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't get any js error it seems that your css rule for `.current` class is less important than some other css rule. In order it to take an effect add the `!important` behind the css values like

```
.current p{
    color: white!important;
    background-color:#2d7a78!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok guys thanks for all your help, im not exactly sure who's answer helped as Im a bit confused but it now works with the following code (i'll go back and tick whoever's answer ended up helping the most - but thanks to all for your help, the guys on this site really are great!!)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav_bar ul li a').click(function(e)     
{$('a').removeClass('current');$(this).addClass('current');});});


</script>
```

For those wishing to know the solution I think I needed to reference the div the list was in and not just a list so adding #nav_bar before the ul li a seems to have solved the problem